# Observable value is not updated in Computed Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have declared view model like this

```
var EditViewModel = function () {
  var Test= ko.observable(0);
  var options= ko.computed(function() {
      Test(1);
      return '';
  });

   return {
      // properties
      Test: Test,
      options: options
   };
}
```

I am trying to assign value to Test in computed function but its not updating, still the value is 0.
Please help to update the Test value in computed.
Thanks

Comment: You're never actually calling `options` how do you expect it to update `Test`?

Answer (score 1):

Your Model should look like this:

```
var EditViewModel = function (data) {
  var self = this;

  self.Test = ko.observable(0);

  self.options = ko.computed(function() {
      var test = self.Test();
      return test;
  });
}
```

Do your really want to update `Test` in a computed?
Maybe you would want:

```
  self.options = ko.computed(function() {
      var test = self.Test();
      return test + 1;
  });
```

If you want to update `Test`, `modelVariable.Test(1);` this would update `options` automatically.